# Find out, why I'm so happy today

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Find out, why I'm so happy today.

[image: Why Happy]

Comment: Congratulations!  No small feat :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As already...

> shown in the rightmost cell of the second row, for each cell, we need to take the difference of the two cells above it. The resulting configuration is:
>  [image]

Now we need to

> Take the letters corresponding to the numbers in order, yielding:  **CELEBRATING MY ONE HUNDRED PUZZLES**.
>  <sub>(Note that some numbers are missing: namely, 15,24,27,31,33. I guess we simply ignore them.)</sub>

Congratulations!